# Scriptmanager Does not work on partial postback Only on Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I am facing very strange problem. I have tried many thing but could not get it solved. Here is the scenario.

I have a `GridView` with 40 records. I am registering a script in `OnRowDataBound` Event of `GridView`. I registered using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`. `GridView` is inside an `UpdatePanel` and `UpdatePanel` is refreshed after one minute.

When first time Page is loaded , My script works fine. But after Partial PostBack it stops working on Firefox. It is working on Chrome, IE, Safari and Opera. It is only Firefox which is creating problem.

I have tried many solutions available on Internet but nothing working for me. Also, When page is partially loaded I am not registering the script again as it has been already registered. For Firefox I have tried by registering the script on partial postback too but no luck. This is how I am registering:

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this);
if (scriptManager != null && !scriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack)
 {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.UpdatePanel5, this.UpdatePanel5.GetType(), e.Row.RowIndex.ToString(), "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Error Message');</script>", false);
                //
}
```

I have tried by changing the last argument of RegisterStartupScript to True and removing the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `IsInAsyncPostBack` check, also make your script name more unique.  I also tend to use `RegisterScriptBlock` instead, that is a preference:

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this);
if (scriptManager != null)
{
      ScriptManager.RegisterScriptBlock(this.UpdatePanel5 + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(), this.UpdatePanel5.GetType(), e.Row.RowIndex.ToString(), "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Error Message');</script>", false);

}
```

Comment: If I remove IsInAsyncPostBack  The It will add duplicate scripts for same purpose. It will confuse the browser. I have also tried scriptname = guid and RegisterScriptBlock . Nothing worked.